# Standard Structure for Object-Value Pairs

Tags: oop

I'm attempting to create a class, A, that has a collection of objects, X[]. 
Each element in X will contain a reference to another class, B, and associate a Boolean value, U, with that reference.

In this way, I'll be able to create a instance of an object, and poll if it's relationship with X[i] is true, false, or none.

Is there a standard practice for doing this?

The particular problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a array of cells, each of which is defined by a positive or negative relationship to its bounding surfaces.

I want to loop through the cells, and find out the path length of a ray that transverses a series of them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't restrict your thinking to objects or data structures. Think dynamically. If the Boolean value you want to associate to every class can be deduced from some logical rules, at it is likely the case, implement a message that will return that value. Then enumerate the classes and collect the Boolean values by sending the (same) message to all of them.

Then think dynamically again and apply the very same concept to calculate the collection of classes: do not hardcode them in a list or array, implement the message that will select them based on the logic that dictates such selection.

Of course, the ability to do all of this depends on the language of your choice as it will have to support classes as first-class objects. But hey, if you have a problem that can be better expressed in some language, different from the one you are currently using, take the opportunity to give it a try.